# How to set value to login form's submit via themename_form_alter

Tags: forms, theming

I have theme_form_alter function, I want to set input submit value with it too

```
function ivanco_form_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id )
{
    if (in_array( $form_id, array( 'user_login', 'user_login_block')))
    {
        $form['name']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Email' );
        $form['pass']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t( 'Password' );
        $form['name']['#attributes']['title'] = t( 'Введите email, указанный при регистрации' );
        $form['pass']['#attributes']['title'] = t( 'Введите пароль' );  
        $form['submit']['#default_value'] = t( 'Принять' ); // this line doesnt work((  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Next time please use devel module and `dpm()` function to test what form's element is, and then [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7) to see what can you set for it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change login form submit value](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96198/change-login-form-submit-value)

Comment: Not duplicates, @zhilevan - here he changes wrong parameter, there - the proper one. They are a chain of questions as they should be, closing them as dupes would encourage [chameleon question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/225745) behavior, and that's something we **don't want**.

Comment: try this $form['submit']['#value'] = "Search";

Comment: @Bala that's what I said :P (see my answer from 3 hours before your comment). And that what he did, as you can see in his next question.

Answer (score 1):

Buttons and Submits (yes, they are different things in Form API) does not have default value. All you can set for submit is: #access, #after_build, #ajax, #attributes, #button_type (default: 'submit'), #disabled, #element_validate, #executes_submit_callback (default: TRUE), #limit_validation_errors, #name (default: 'op'), #parents, #post_render, #prefix, #pre_render, #process, #submit, #states, #suffix, #theme, #theme_wrappers, #tree, #type, #validate, #value, #weight

As you can see, no #default_value. As user is not supposed to be able to change that value, it's simply #value - no need for defaults.

Read more on [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit).

Comment: @Bala thanks. But to be honest, I'm not sure what to do wit that responsibility. And wasn't that you who argued some of my close votes with fire on Meta? :p